# Heroku saying I don't have Procfile

Tags: node.js, discord.js

basically, i have procfile (without .txt) and it says i dont, so i cant configure dynos on heroku

here is how the repository is like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVYT0.png

the text in procfile:

```js
worker: node bot.js
```

i am horrible at this and i never used StackOverflow so yeah- if you reply to this use an easy language

(this is a discord.js bot)

Comment: Why did you choose the 'worker' process type instead of 'web'?

Comment: uh- i did it on my other bot and it worked and is still working fine; should i change it to web?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some stuff that you might want to try,

1: Making sure that your document is named `.Procfile` (capital P and . before)
2: Checking build logs for errors  [image]
3: Deleting and re-creating your procfile

---

Also you should be using `worker` for a discord bot.

Comment: it still isn't working, i already named it ``.Procfile``, but nothing. my other bot has it named ``Procfile`` (the script inside is ``worker: node bot.js``) and is working.

Comment: the problem is that i cant configure the dynos because it says i have n Procfile, which i do (https://imgur.com/AY782Q6)

anyways, here are my build logs:

part one: https://imgur.com/a/93l41MD
part two: https://imgur.com/a/ZmzTDhY

i just found out it says i have no Procfile; i will try reconnecting to the github

Comment: Have you done `npm init -y` before? the logs says its missing it.

Comment: i didnt know that i had to do this; however, it still says i have no ``Procfile``